# ReportRenderingException MemoryStream length must be non-negative and less than 2^31

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, aspose

We have some SSRS reports that contain several charts. These reports are rendered through a custom .NET MVC app to PDF, or to PowerPoint using Aspose slides.

We recently moved the reports from a 2005 SSRS server to a 2008 R2 SSRS server. The reports mostly work well. One report, however, is throwing the following error whenever the number of pages is large (19) and we try to render to PowerPoint (PDF works okay).

> Error Message: Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: MemoryStream length must be non-negative and less than 2^31 - 1 - origin. Parameter name: offset

The same report renders fine to PowerPoint if different filters are applied that result in fewer pages.

This seems to be an SSRS issue, but I'm not sure. Could it be Aspose, or even the custom .NET app?

Comment: Hi, I'm developer of Aspose.Slides for RS team and I advice you post this question on Aspose forum.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Orsol.  I just posted this issue on the Aspose forum also.  Here's the link, in case it helps someone else with this issue:  http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/showthread.aspx?PostID=429747&Subj=reportrenderingexception-memorystream-length-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-2-31#429747

Comment: I have observed that you were able to fix this issue by removing blank pages from report and now this issue does not appear.